# how to create several url aliases for a page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

on the root page of a WordPress site we have a custom page template, that also handles some forms and dynamically changes part of the content.

Something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
...
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="do_this" />
</form>
```

and then in the page template we check for $_POST['action']=="do_this".
Works perfectly.

Now we would like that when these forms are posted to have the url change (action="/do_this").

For that to work, we need /do_this to deliver the root page, but the url to not change.

we have tried this in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^do_this(.*)$ index.php?p=12 [L]
```

but it changes the browser url.

It must have something with WordPress, since if we use another file

RewriteRule ^do_this(.*)$ test.html [L]

it works: the url is not changed and the test.html is being delivered.

Thanks.

Comment: so you mean to not refresh page but send the form data ? why don't you use ajax to handle it.

Comment: @amit: the page will refresh, the data it will be normally posted, but the new url should be mapped only internally to the same page

Comment: do you want to keep the url `/do-this/` but with the content of index.php ?

Comment: yes :) true. basically to have the do-this url deliver the content of the root page, but i keep getting 404 errors from WP or apache does a redirect. this all works for another file, not index.php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a colleague fixed it using parse_request.

similar to this one:

http://willnorris.com/2009/06/wordpress-plugin-pet-peeve-2-direct-calls-to-plugin-files

Comment: this is not a valid answer, please add more information that actually show how you solved the problem.